# JSON not working in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari it works as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've a list that autopopulates from a JSON file:

```
<div class="conversionFormES" id="from1">
            <label for="from">Convert From:</label>
                <select size = "10" name="from" id="from" onchange="convertUnits()">
                    <option value="from">-Select an Option-</option>
                    <option value="from">Firefox</option>
                </select>
</div>
```

I added the 'Firefox' option just to make sure something was being displayed and it is.

Any ideas what the problem could be.  Just to re-iterate, it works perfectly with chrome and safari.  Many thanks.

ConvertUnits function:

```
function convertUnits(){

var convertObj = new Convert($("#from"), $("#to"), $("#units"), $("#result"));
var measurementType = $("#from option:selected").attr("class");
var result = "invalid input";
var input = parseInt(convertObj.units.val());

// convertObj.convertUnitsFromHash();
if(measurementType == "temp"){
    convertObj.convertTemp();

}else{

    convertObj.convertUnitsFromHash();
}
console.log('Measurement Type:', measurementType);

}
```

JSON Script called after the HTML Form.

```
        <script>
        //        JSON:
        //        The key is the class identifier, temp, area etc etc
        //        Value is being used for both ID and Value when the list is being populated
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

                console.log(data);
                //for testing output only
                var list = $("<ul />");

                $.each(data, function (key, conversions) {
                    console.log(key + ":" + conversions);

                    $.each(conversions, function (index, conversion) {
                        console.log("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");

                        if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

                            $("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                            $("#to").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                            //testing output
                            var elem = $("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);
                        }
                    });
                });
                //$("#testJSON").html(list);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

EDIT: JSON sample:

```
{
"angle": [
    {
        "value": "degree",
        "name": "Degree(deg)"
    },
    {
        "value": "radian",
        "name": "Radian(rad)"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Post the JSON message as well

Comment: @AstDerek - JSON message?

Comment: @user2608855 your Json is not well formated. Please check on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @aka - it is, that above is just a sample, ran it again to be sure.  Result: Valid JSON

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` spit out on Firefox?